# How Fourier-Lebsgue spaces operates functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$ such that $ab> 1$ ; put

$$L^{1}_{a}(\mathbb R)= \{ f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C  \ \text {measurable} : ||(1+|x|)^{a}f||_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}< \infty \},$$

and

$$FL^{1}_{b}(\mathbb R)= \{ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C \ \text {measurable} : ||(1+|w|)^{b} \hat {f}||_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}< \infty \}.$$

We consider a Foureier-Lebsgue space,
$$FL:=L^{1}_{a}(\mathbb R) \cap FL^{1}_{b}(\mathbb R).$$

**My question is**: Let  $f\in FL$. 
Can we expect   $|f|\in FL$ ; Or we get a counter example ?

---

Thanks to math fraternity;-)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no. Take, for example for example if $a=1,b=2$.
The function 
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin\pi x}{x(x^2-1)}$$
has Fourier transform with compact support, by Paley-Wiener, or by direct computation, so it belongs to your space.
However $|f|$ is not differentiable at some points, therefore it cannot belong to
your space (your condition on the Fourier transform with $b=2$ permits to
differentiate $f$).